# nextjs revalidate on-demand raise error 504

Tags: next.js, vercel, ondemand

I have to revalidate two pages. The root "/" and a certain post eg. "posts/123".

All two revalidating work well on localhost but, on the Vercel when revalidate the root path, it raises error "504 deployment error"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's due to you hitting the Vercel limit on serverless API routes which is 10 seconds of runtime. Everything that takes longer is gonna cause this error.

Comment: You mean the root page building time is longer than 10 seconds?